# Composer (installing / updating) always fails

Tags: php, curl, composer-php

I have a stable connection, however composer always throws `Composer\Downloader\TransportException` when I run `composer update` on my project root, followed by messages stating that I had a timeout error while downloading the files.

After running `composer diagnose`, everything seems to pass the test.

I attempted uninstalling, and, afterwards, I could not install composer. When I download composer with `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`, composer prints this to the stream:

```
 ~  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Download failed: Failed to open https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar (Operation timed out after 4994 milliseconds with 229148 out of 1016883 bytes received)
Downloading...
Download failed: Failed to open https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar (Operation timed out after 4988 milliseconds with 261916 out of 1016883 bytes received)
Downloading...
SlowTimer [5000ms] at curl: https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
Download failed: Failed to open https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar (Operation timed out after 4996 milliseconds with 147228 out of 1016883 bytes received)
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

Any ideas on why this keeps happening?

Comment: Permissions? Try running it with `sudo`.

Comment: Check your network connectivity

Comment: @hek2mgl My friend's machine could use composer with no problems.

Comment: @hcoat - No difference, eh.

Comment: can you `ping getcomposer.org` ?

Comment: Seems to be fine. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vbnmv5cg). And it's even still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this applies to  your reinstall option, but it might apply to your initial timeout problem (in addition to the suggestions of Vector); I was using [hhvm to run composer](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/hhvm-hack-part-2), which specifies its own request timeout parameters, which override anything that you specify in your composer.json or the environment variables.  The previous link contains the appropriate information to configure your timeout in more detail, but my example bash alias may help.

```
alias composer='hhvm -v ResourceLimit.SocketDefaultTimeout=60 -v Http.SlowQueryThreshold=60000 -v Eval.Jit=false /home/liam/bin/composer'
```

Answer (score 2):

I advised on this before. Try `composer update/install -o -vvv` and check wether the package is being loaded from composer's cache.

if yes try clearing composer's cache or try adding `-cache-dir=/dev/null`.

To force downloading an archive instead of cloning sources, use the `--prefer-dist` option in combination with `--no-dev`.

Otherwise you could try raising composer's process timeout value:

`export COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=600   ( defaults to 300 )`

Comment: Still, I'll have to get composer first. Any ideas?